# Dojo sortable table

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm new to dojo but it's what my team uses.  I've searched on Google and have found an example of a sortable table, but I can't find any dojo documentation regarding the use of it which makes me think it's deprecated.  The table head is declared in HTML and the table body is built using jstl.  I just want a table that sorts based on column clicks.  I know that there is a jQuery plug-in, but I'm looking for a dojo solution.  The DataGrid has more functionality than I want and need.

Is there a dojo sortable table or will I have to use Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of tables/grids based on Dojo.  Yes, the one you mention is deprecated.  There are newer, lighter alternatives to DataGrid being developed.  Try [dgrid](https://github.com/kriszyp/dgrid) or [gridx](https://github.com/dojo/demos/tree/master/gridx)